# Unable to push Docker image to Artifactory

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I am running a Jenkins Pipeline and trying to upload a docker image but it is failing using the Artifactory command.

This is a snippet of my Jenkinsfile stage:

```
stage("Build docker image") {
     steps {
         container('docker') {
             sh 'docker -v'
             script {
                 def rtServer = Artifactory.server "artifactory"
                 def rtDocker = Artifactory.docker server: rtServer
                 docker.build("app", "--build-arg JAR_FILE=app.jar -f Dockerfile .")

                 def buildInfo = rtDocker.push '<companyname>.jfrog.io/app','docker-snapshot-local'
             }
         }
     }
}
```

This fails after the `docker.build` with the following message:

```
[Pipeline] newBuildInfo
[Pipeline] dockerPushStep
expected to call org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.common.types.Docker.push but wound up catching dockerPushStep; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/pipeline-cps-method-mismatches/
[Pipeline] }
```

Jenkins EOF log:

```
Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from ip-XX-XX-XX-XX.ec2.internal/XX.XX.XX.XX:42790
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1743)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:357)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:957)
        at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.common.docker.utils.DockerAgentUtils.getImageIdFromAgent(DockerAgentUtils.java:291)
        at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.common.executors.DockerExecutor.execute(DockerExecutor.java:59)
        at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.scripted.steps.DockerPushStep$Execution.run(DockerPushStep.java:104)
        at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.scripted.steps.DockerPushStep$Execution.run(DockerPushStep.java:71)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
        at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at ...io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel.doConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:713)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollDomainSocketChannel.doConnect(EpollDomainSocketChannel.java:87)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.connect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:555)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:545)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:530)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.connect(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.connect(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:47)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.connect(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:298)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:545)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:530)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:512)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1024)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.connect(AbstractChannel.java:259)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$3.run(Bootstrap.java:252)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:335)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: The link in the error message gives you some pretty comprehensive steps to debug the problem.

Comment: @gareth_bowles Perhaps if I wasn't using the Artifactory Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The `expected to call...` is just a warning message and you can ignore it. This may disappear in the next version of workflow-cps-plugin. More information about it can be found [here](http://%20https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/pull/314.).

About the error - Try first to follow the instructions here [HAP-1241](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/HAP-1241?focusedCommentId=73680&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-73680).